# Return document in each group with max value using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a dataset:

```
{_id: 0, type: 'banana', amount: 5}
{_id: 1, type: 'banana', amount: 3}
{_id: 2, type: 'apple', amount: 8}
{_id: 3, type: 'apple', amount: 2}
```

What is the most efficient way of getting only the records of the same `type`, that has the highest `amount`?

The expected result is:

```
{_id: 0, type: 'banana', amount: 5}
{_id: 2, type: 'apple', amount: 8}
```

Right now I'm doing it this way, but it seems kinda silly:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { 'amount': -1 } },
  { $group: {
     _id: '$type',
     group: {
       $push: '$$ROOT'
     }
   }, {
     $replaceRoot: {
       newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$group", 0] }
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: Try `collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { 'amount': -1 } },
  { $group: {
     _id: '$type',
     group: {
       $first: '$$ROOT'
     }
   }
   }
])`

Comment: That actually makes it slightly less ugly, but I still have to pull out the single group object as the new root. Is there a way to just return the document that is the highest in the group?

Comment: There is no such way. You have to use `$replaceRoot` to promote the "group" field to top.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. If you want some internet points, type it out as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) amount descending followed by [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to project max amount document.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the max amount document to top level.

```
collection.aggregate([
 {$sort:{'amount':-1}}, 
 {$group:{ _id: '$type',group:{$first:'$$ROOT'}}},
 {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$group"}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variant on C# with mixing FilterDefinitions for matching and that mongo query language for sorting\grouping\replacing:

```
var someFilters = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq("field1.subField2", "some_value");
var result = collection.Aggregate()
                                .Match(filters)
                                .Sort("{'amount':-1}")
                                .Group("{ _id: '$type', group: {$first: '$$ROOT'} }")
                                .ReplaceRoot<MyModel>("$group")
                                .ToList();
```